# Difference between Java and Kotlin for-loop syntax

Tags: kotlin

I recently started learning Kotlin and for-loop syntax of Kotlin is different from Java.

**How would I duplicate the following Java for loop in Kotlin?
**

```
void funa(int a){
  for(int i = 0; a >= 1024; i++){
    a /= 1024;
  }
  System.out.println("val " + a + " stesps " + i)
}
```

I know i can do something like this

```
fun funa(a: Long){
    var b = a
    var i = 0;
    while (b>= 1024){ 
        b /= 1024
        i++
    }
}
```

but it looks realy stupid

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin does not provide the for loop based on a counter, but only the for-each operation. In many cases we can replace traditional loops with a for-each over a range, for example:

```kotlin
for (i in 0..8) { }
```

Of course, in your case this is not possible. In this case we should use your suggested solution based on `while`.

Comment: Indeed. In my experience, in general programming almost all loops can be done using a for-each — or, often, omitted completely by calling `map()` or similar list-based functions instead (which tend to be more concise, more efficient, and easier to read). I can't remember the last time I had to use a `while` for a definite loop (i.e. one in which the number of iterations was fixed).

Answer (score 1):

Your Java code doesn't make sense--to be able to log `i` after the loop, you would have to declare `i` before the loop, so it would have to look like:

```
int i = 0;
for(; a >= 1024; i++){
    a /= 1024;
}
System.out.println("val " + a + " steps " + i);
```

That doesn't look any more or less stupid than:

```
var i = 0
while (a >= 1024) {
    a /= 1024
    i++
}
println("val $a steps $i")
```

It's just different syntax. It could be argued the Kotlin version is easier to read at the expense of number of lines, because it is more explicit and doesn't have the weird empty expression before the first `;`.

It's a design decision that Kotlin doesn't have the `for(;;)` syntax. I think their reasoning is that it's confusing. It may not seem confusing if we've been using any C-syntax-based language for years, but to a brand new programmer, that syntax has a lot of individual elements to remember, contributing to a complex group of behaviors.

It's far more common for Java for-loops to simply be iterating something a pre-determined number of times. For that, you can use the `repeat` function:

```
repeat(10) { i ->
    println("Count $i")
}
```

Or if you are iterating a collection's indices:

```
for (i in list.indices) {
    println("Item $i is ${list[i]}")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, your proposal looks good already. It's actually better than the Java equivalent, because in that one you imply that the counter influences the loop condition which is not the case. You merely want to count the steps as a side-effect.

---

In Kotlin you cannot use a for loop for that use-case because:

> for iterates through anything that provides an iterator. ([source](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#for-loops))

Try not to overengineer things, you already have proper Kotlin code.